# Creating a haze mask in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I created a cloud-free median composite for a selected time and location from Landsat 5 SR imagery. Unfortunately, significant portions of the composite appear hazy and for the hazy pixels, the red, green, and blue band values are twice what they should be. I would like to apply a haze mask similar to the various cloud masks available but using the sr_atmos_opacity band. Unfortunately,  attempts to modify existing cloud mask codes (e.g., like the one below) have failed to do anything.

How do I mask pixels from the collection when sr_atmos_opacity is >0.3 (or 300 unscaled)?

```
var cloudMaskL457 = function(image) {   
     var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');   
     var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
              .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
              .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3));
}; 
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
              .filterDate('1990-05-14', '1990-09-14')
              .map(cloudMaskL457).filterBounds(geometry); 
  return image.updateMask(cloud.not());
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the specific application to cloud masking, but the code you show cannot work because the function `cloudMaskL457` does not return anything. It just declares variables `qa` and `cloud` and does nothing with them. You need to `return` the image you want.

I tried adding this and it seemed to do something reasonable:

```
return image.mask(cloud.not());
```

---

> Any advice on how best to mask pixels from the collection when sr_atmos_opacity is >0.3 (or 300 unscaled) would be most appreciated.

Again, I'm not familiar with the data set or science, but this should be simple to do:

```
function mask_by_sr_atmos_opacity() {
  return image.mask(image.select('sr_atmos_opacity').lte(300));
}
```

A mask image needs to have value 1 for the pixels you want to *keep*, and 0 for the pixels you want to discard, so we're using `lte` to select pixels whose `sr_atmos_opacity` value is *less than or equal to* 300.

In this case you don't need any of the `qa` or `cloud` definitions, unless you want to mask by those as well (which might be best done as a separate function, to keep things clearer).

Comment: I updated the cloud mask in the original post to include the return command, in case anyone else uses it in the future. I somehow managed not to copy it the first time around. Nonethess, I modified the code you sent just a little and it worked great to filter out the haze. 
var hazeMask = function (image) {
  return image.mask(image.select('sr_atmos_opacity').lte(300));
}
var l5 = l5.map(hazeMask)